# perl: What would cause perl to not find a file that exists?

Tags: perl

Running a perl cgi script I got the error it couldn't find the file it was trying to open. I check apache error log /var/log/apache2/error.log:

```
[Tue Jan 13 20:59:17 2015] [error] [client ::1] [Tue Jan 13 20:59:17 2015] submit.cgi: [Tue Jan 13 20:59:17 2015] submit.cgi: 
/home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13/grades4.txt: No such file or directory at /var/www/homeworks/hw13/CreateExam.pm line 48., referer: http://localhost/homeworks/hw13/test.cgi
```

double check:

```
root@debian-macbook:/var/log/apache2# ls -l /home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13/grades4.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jddancks jddancks 2095 Jan  7 12:25 /home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13/grades4.txt
```

Why would this happen? This is a debian machine running apache 2.2 IDK if that helps.

There are 2 files: submit.cgi and CreateExam.pm.
submit.cgi:

```
use CreateExam;
...
my $path = `pwd`;
...
my $check = CreateExam->new("${path}/exam4.txt","${path}/answers4.txt","${path}/grades4.txt",$pathroot);
$check->entergrades($cookie_value,$cgi->Vars());
```

CreateExam.pm:

```
package CreateExam;

sub new {
    my ($class,$file,$answers,$grades,$script) = @_;
    #print "<p>in new: file: $file, grades: $grades</p>\n";
    return bless {'file'=>$file,'answers'=>$answers,'gradefile'=>$grades,'script'=>$script},$class;
}

sub tooktest {
    my ($self,$person) = @_;
    #print "<p>in tooktest: person: $person</p>\n";
    my $grades = $self->{'gradefile'};
    open(ANS,"< $grades") or die "$grades: $!";
    my $found = 0;
    LAST: while(my $line = <ANS>) {
        if($line =~ /\<test taker=$person/) { $found = 1; last LAST;}
    }
    return $found==1;
}
```

---

Data::Dumper:

```
$VAR1 = "/home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13"; (in browser)
```

hexdump:

```
jddancks@debian-macbook:~/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13$ perl -e 'print qx(pwd)' | hexdump -C
00000000  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 6a 64  64 61 6e 63 6b 73 2f 44  |/home/jddancks/D|
00000010  6f 63 75 6d 65 6e 74 73  2f 70 65 72 6c 2f 68 6f  |ocuments/perl/ho|
00000020  6d 65 77 6f 72 6b 73 2f  68 77 31 33 0a           |meworks/hw13.|
0000002d
```

Comment: Is there any chance you will provide `submit.cgi` code or we have to figure out what it is ?

Comment: Its pretty long. I'll see if I can just put the relevant snippets.

Comment: Does the `pwd` generated string contain a newline? You may need to `chomp` it. Also, instead of using `LAST:` label and the somewhat cryptic `return $found == 1`, you could just replace `$found = 1; last LAST;` with `return 1`. And then replace `return $found == 1` with `return 0`.

Comment: @jasondancks maybe the apache user has no permissions to read on of the directories?

Comment: @Jens Wouldn't the error be `Permission denied` in that case?

Comment: >> `pwd` => http://perldoc.perl.org/Cwd.html <<

Comment: Technically, you do not need to get the current directory with `pwd`, you can just use relative paths, or no path if you want the current dir.

Comment: @TLP I am not sure if the user has no read permissions it also can be a `file not found`

Comment: @TLP: I forgot to append `$path =~ s/\s//g;`. I had that problem earlier. Even with the correct path I still have this problem.

Comment: @jasondancks Try this: `use Data::Dumper; $Data::Dumper::Useqq=1; print Dumper $path` See if you have any strange characters in your string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your hexdump shows, `pwd` returns the working directory followed by a newline, and that is what is you are assigning to $path.  Then you try to open `"/home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13\n/grades4.txt"` which indeed has a directory that does not exist.

Try doing:

```
chomp( my $path = `pwd` );
```

Comment: It didn't help thats not the issue

Comment: in your script, if you try to explicitly open the hardcoded filename '/home/jddancks/Documents/perl/homeworks/hw13/grades4.txt', what error do you get?  (e.g. `print "got error $! (".($!+0).")\n";`)

Comment: I got:  got error No such file or directory (2). I even recently tried setting up suExec on my machine (debian). Didn't help. I know for a fact the file exists. Could some weird corruption possibly be the cause?

Comment: seems like either the cgi script is running on a different server than you expect or is chroot'd to not have the whole filesystem exposed.  in the script, try printing `join(",",glob("/*"),glob("/home/*"))` to see what's there

Comment: heh. I uhh... had the append symbol pointed the wrong way: `<<` and tried to write to it.

Answer (score 1):

If Apache is configured to run in a `chroot` it does not see `/home` on the host system at all.